# Pylint cannot recognize gmpy2 members

Tags: python, pylint, gmpy

I use pylint and gmpy2 on Kali Linux(WSL2). Pylint makes many complaints about being unable to find gmpy2 members. How can I avoid this?

Here is a little example:

```
import gmpy2
print(gmpy2.is_even(6))
```

And the result of pylint is

> tst.py:2:6: E1101: Module 'gmpy2' has no 'is_even' member (no-member)

I also tried this on ArchLinux, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/c_extensions.html)

> If you are getting the dreaded no-member error, there is a possibility
> that either pylint found a bug in your code or that it actually tries
> to lint a C extension module.
>
> Linting C extension modules is not supported out of the box,
> especially since pylint has no way to get an AST object out of the
> extension module.

You should add `extension-pkg-whitelist` argument in command line or the pylintrc file.

Here is the original [issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4436) I opened in the Github.